# Variable is not incremented in ISR

Tags: c, embedded

I have an ISR which increments a variable 'head' of an array. The problem is after a few hours this variable even after getting incremented comes back to its previous value. Something like:

```
array[head] = val; 
head++;
/*val is the byte that came from ISR and I am assigning it to my buffer 'array' at head position*/
```

Now when I run the code for several hours, I observe that if head was say 119, stored the byte from ISR, became 120, and on next Interrupt instead of storing the next byte on 120 and incrementing head to 121, head becomes 120 again and overwrites that byte in my array. What could be the problem? Any suggestions are welcome!

Note:

- head is a volatile variable.
- Speed of interrupt is very high.

code snippet:

```
    /*before storing on to the circular buffer check whether it is full*/

    if ((COM1RxBufHead == COM1RxBufTail - 1) ||((COM1RxBufHead == (COM1RXBUFSIZE - 1)) && (COM1RxBufTail == 0)))
    {

        logDEBUG("[FULL]");
        U1STAbits.OERR = 0;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Byte can be safely stored on to buffer*/
        COM1RxBuf[COM1RxBufHead] = U1RXREG;


        if (COM1RxBufHead == (COM1RXBUFSIZE - 1))
        {
            COM1RxBufHead = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            COM1RxBufHead++;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the actual code? Does it happen always, or from time to time? If the first is true, why you need to run it for several hours?

Comment: Two different calls of the ISR may run simultaniously, declaring the variable as `volatile` doesn't ensure, that it is read from memory, modified and written back. You might need to use some kind of locking?

Comment: This ISR, as I understand it, is atomic. Also while reading I take lock to avoid any other interrupt. Please elaborate a little more what you meant something else.

Comment: so you are sure the ISR doesn't nest?

Comment: is it on multicore or single core ?

Comment: Do you get any [FULL] log entries?  Does the logDEBUG() call work safely from an interrupt-handler?

Comment: Does COM1RxBufTail get modified outside of the interrupt?  When it is, are interrupts blocked during this?  If not, your ISR can fire in the middle of a "read/modify/write" operation, and once back from the ISR you'll have an incorrect value for the tail, which will make your isFull() check fail...

Comment: @Martin James: No I din't get any 'FULL' log entries, and I'll check into logDEBUG() call. Thanx

Comment: @Ross: yes interrupts are disabled while we are reading buffer or modifying tail.

Comment: where is `head` declared? is it local for ISR only?

Comment: If you are able to set a breakpoint on variable change, a quick and dirty way of seeing what value the ISR reads for COM1RxBufHead is to do something like: `else { volatile head_type_t checkMe = COM1RxBufHead; COM1RxBufHead++;}` Set the change break point on COM1RxBufHead, then when execution breaks, check the value of checkMe to ensure the ISR read the expected value. If correct and you are sure there are no nested ISRs next step would be to check disassembly I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working at the wrong abstraction level. Although it's perfectly okay to *use* C for coding this stuff up, finding problems that seem to be impossible based on the C code itself means that you need to step down one level.

And that means going into the assembler/machine-architecture arena.

The following are general suggestions only since I don't actually *know* your machine architecture.

- Examine the actual assembly language that's generated by your compiler. Seeing the translated code *may* make it obvious what could be causing this issue, such as the use of cached values (even though you state that you've marked the variable `volatile`).
- Make *sure* that further interrupts are disable while you're running the ISR. I don't know off the top of my head any architectures where this isn't the case but they *may* exist, requiring you to disable and re-enable manually.
- Even if interrupts *are* automatically disabled in the ISR, there are architectures that have priority levels of interrupts, where a higher priority one can interrupt a lower priority ISR in progress. There are also NMIs, non-maskable interrupts, which can interrupt anything (though they tend to be used for more serious things).
- Make sure that, if you're modifying the variable outside of the ISR, you disable interrupts while doing it. That's to prevent the possibility of an ISR running halfway through an update, if the update itself isn't an atomic operation interrupt-wise. That's likely to be the case since incrementing a pointer with potential circular buffer wrap-around will almost certainly be a multiple instruction (and hence interruptible) process.